# BizTalk Receive binary file correlated on RecievedFileName

Tags: properties, routes, biztalk, correlation, biztalk-orchestrations

I'm having problem with routing a message of binary file to a running instance of an `Orchestration` using correlation of context property: `ReceivedFileName`. The correlation is initialized using a send with dummy file where in the `Orchestration` sets the `ReceivedFileName` context property of the message and the property gets promoted. After that **routing fails** of the message being received (as `XmlDocument`) and I can see that the `ReveivedFileName` context property of that message has **not been promoted** should it be like that?  I cant figure out any way to get it promoted so I just want to make sure it should be like this.

The file names are identical but I noticed that the `ReceivedFileName` property of the send message doesn't have the path whereas the received message has path + file name.  I have tried to add the path to the send message(sounds strange though, read it some where) but it doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: Sorry, but you problem statement isn't very clear on what you're trying to do and some of the terms don't match with others.  Can you briefly describe the result you're looking for?

Comment: Getting routing of binary file to running instance of an orchestration.Have used correlation on context property: ReceivedFileName, initialized on send shape and gets promoted when sent out (msg(FILE.ReceivedFileName) = "MyBinFile";). however once receiveing the binary file the ReceivedFileName property is not promoted and i suspect that's the reason why routing fails.

Comment: How are you Promoting FILE.ReceivedFileName?  In an Orchestration, you have to use the Correlation Technique.

Comment: Yes, i'm using correlation. I have a correlation type where the "Correlation properties" is set to FILE.ReceivedFileName type. And as i mentioned i can see that the property is promoted when sent but when receiving the property it is not promoted.

Answer (score 0):

While you can set Context Proerties in an Orchestration, they are *not* Promoted.

You have to use the Correlation Technique described here to have the Properties Promoted when they hit the MessageBox: http://blogs.biztalk360.com/property-promotion-inside-orchestration/

Basically, you Initialize a Correlation Set based on the Properties you need Promoted.

Comment: Yes and this is exactly what i'm doing, create a Correlation type of FILE.ReceivedFileName
initialize it on the send shape and it gets promoted when sent out. But later when receiving a binary file on the 
receive location (receive shape is set to follow correlation) routing fails and I can see that the FILE.ReceivedFileName is not promoted for that message.
The file names are identical. I guess i have to explain the process in more detail. must be something else that prevents the routing.

Comment: If you have Failed Message Routing enabled, all Properties that were previously Promoted are demoted in order to prevent a continuous loop so what you see is likely normal.

Comment: Mustin - Are you promoting the File.ReceivedFileName when you are receiving the binary file?  When this file is picked up you will need to promote the FILE.ReceivedFileName in a pipeline component.

Comment: I should also mention that you can verify FILE.ReceivedFileName is getting Promoted in the Orchestration by Stopping the target Send Port, then examining the Context.

Comment: Ben - Ok, so i have to have a pipeline component in order the get that type of property promoted?

Comment: No, you can Promote it in the Orchestration.  But if you're looking at the Failed Message, it will not be Promoted.  That is the expected behavior.

Comment: i didn't get the promotion to work on the receive side with correlation. however @BenRunchey approach worked, i was trying to avoid the custom pipeline solution but there is only so much frustration one can take ;)

Answer (score 0):

As Ben Runchey pointed out in a comment above one have to resort to a custom pipeline and promote the **FILE.ReceivedFileName** there by calling:

```
messag.Context.Promote("ReceivedFileName", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/file-properties", receivedFileName);
```

I also removed the path from **FILE.ReceivedFileName** to only have the filename by calling the `inmsg.Context.Read("ReceivedFileName", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/file-properties")`

and altered the value and wrote it back by calling:

```
inmsg.Context.Write("ReceivedFileName", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/file-properties", receivedFileName);
```

Comment: As a side note, because you have to Promote this value on your own, it would be a better implementation to define your own custom property rather than reuse a system property.  Promoting FILE.ReceivedFileName will work fine though.